# Sample code for zebra scanner SDK gives syntax errors

Tags: c#, zebra

I'm trying to learn the zebra scanner SDK and have everything set up for it in visual studio, but the sample code given within the documentation gives the error

> "Error CS1752  Interop type 'CCoreScannerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead."

the code I'm trying to use is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using CoreScanner;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        // Declare CoreScannerClass
        static CCoreScannerClass cCoreScannerClass;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate CoreScanner Class
            cCoreScannerClass = new CCoreScannerClass();
            //Call Open API
            short[] scannerTypes = new short[1]; // Scanner Types you are interested in
            scannerTypes[0] = 1; // 1 for all scanner types
            short numberOfScannerTypes = 1; // Size of the scannerTypes array
            int status; // Extended API return code
            cCoreScannerClass.Open(0, scannerTypes, numberOfScannerTypes, out status);
            if (status == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CoreScanner API: Open Successful");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CoreScanner API: Open Failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've mainly just tried different ways of defining the class and referencing CCoreScannerClass seems to lead to an error not matter what.

Comment: Try instantiate Core Scanner class this way cCoreScanner = new CCoreScanner();